# OpenWhisk invoke watson text to speech action from an action

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, openwhisk

I am trying to invoke an action included into Watson system package (text to speech) from an OpenWhisk action.

I have binded the service and set-up the credentials and so from the CLI I can see

```
wsk list
entities in namespace: xxxxxx
packages
/xxxxxx/myWatson                           private binding
```

Here is my OpenWhisk action:

```
function main(param) {
   //code here for my action. At the end, I invoke the text to speech        

   if (...) {
      textToSpeech(param.text);
    }
    else {
        return whisk.error(error);
    }
    return whisk.async();
}

function textToSpeech(text){
    whisk.invoke({
      name:'myWatson/textToSpeech',
      parameters:{
        payload: text,
        voice: 'en-US_MichaelVoice',
        accept: 'audio/wav',
        encoding: 'base64'
      },
      blocking: true,
      next: function(error, activation){
        if(error){
            return whisk.error(error);
        }
        else{
            return whisk.done({msg:'success'});
        }
      }
   });
}
```

And I get the following error

```
"response": {
    "result": {
        "error": "The requested resource does not exist. (undefined)"
    },
    "status": "application error",
    "success": false
}
```

Can you help understanding what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the action should be fully qualified to include the namespace. From your CLI output, it looks like your package is `/xxxxxx/myWatson` so your action reference in the `whisk.invoke` should be `/xxxxxx/myWatson/textToSpeech`.